# Why SUM is faster when we are using SMALLINT instead DECIMAL

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions, sql-types

Are there any known rules saying some T-SQL types are better for calculations?

I have two identical tables containing numbers - one with `SMALLINT` fields and second with `DECIMAL(9,2)` fields.
I am performing the following operations over them (two queries):

```
SUM(CAST(A AS BIGINT))
SUM(CAST(A AS BIGINT))
CAST(CAST(SUM(A) AS decimal) / CASE SUM(B) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM(B) END * 100 AS decimal(18, 0))
CAST(CAST(SUM(A) AS decimal) / CASE SUM(B) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM(B) END * 100 AS decimal(18, 1)) 

SUM(CAST(A AS DECIMAL(19,2))) 
SUM(CAST(A AS DECIMAL(19,2)))
CAST(SUM(CAST([A] AS DECIMAL(19, 2))) / IIF(SUM(CAST([B] AS DECIMAL(19, 2))) = 0, NULL, SUM(CAST([B] AS DECIMAL(19, 2)))) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19, 0))
CAST(SUM(CAST([A] AS DECIMAL(19, 2))) / IIF(SUM(CAST([B] AS DECIMAL(19, 2))) = 0, NULL, SUM(CAST([B] AS DECIMAL(19, 2)))) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19, 1))
```

and there the query results are about:

- 29 seconds for the table with decimal columns
- 18 seconds for the table with smallint columns

The only difference is in the byes for each type:

- smallint is [2 bytes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)
- decimal(9,2) is [5 bytes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Is this the reason `SMALLINT` is faster then `DECIMAL(9,2)` for such operations?

Note: I have the same values in each tables - I have not got decimal numbers - only whole numbers.

Comment: I'm very curious about the performance with this modification:  Change "CASE SUM(B) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM(B) END" To: NullIf(SUM(B), 0)

Comment: @GMastros it takes the same time, but I am going to use your syntax with `NULLIF` because it is better for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's true. Smallint values need less space on disk and the IO operation have much more performance. It's always a good idea to have as 'small' type as it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx):

> Converting from decimal or numeric to float or real can cause some loss of precision. Converting from int, smallint, tinyint, float, real, money, or smallmoney to either decimal or numeric can cause overflow.
>
> By default, SQL Server uses rounding when converting a number to a decimal or numeric value with a lower precision and scale. However, if the SET ARITHABORT option is ON, SQL Server raises an error when overflow occurs. Loss of only precision and scale is not sufficient to raise an error.

This strongly implies that  extra operations surround `decimal` arithmetic, specifically scaling, rounding, and range checking.   All of those are substantially harder (more computation intensive) than addition, especially on an x86 CPU.

The fastest datatypes are those native to the CPU—usually `char` and `integer`— and should be fastest on most SQL platforms.